# build a regex that begins with string1 but doesn't end in string2

Tags: regex

here is my test list:

```
compiz
compizconfig-settings-manager
compiz-fusion-bcop
compiz-plugins-default
compiz-plugins-main-default
compizconfig-backend-gconf
compiz-corecompiz-gnome
compiz-plugins-extra
compiz-plugins-main-dev
compizconfig-backend-kconfig
compiz-dev
compiz-plugins
compiz-plugins-main
```

I'm regex noob and trying to match `compiz-*(?!-dev)`
anything that begins with `compiz-` but doesn't end in `-dev`

I'm using http://www.regexr.com/ to test my strings and i'm lost.

```
^compiz
```

only matches `compiz` but nothing that follows it. I get that `(?!-dev)` should exclude the ending of `-dev` but how do I tell it to continue after the string?

```
^compiz(!?-dev)
```

matches ONLY `compiz-dev`

how does that even make sense if !? is supposed to say exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be as follows:

```
^compiz(?!.*-dev$).*
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/dB9iE6

Comment: He said it has to begin with `compiz-`. You're missing the `-`.

Comment: This also excludes `compiz-foo-dev-bar` even though it doesn't end with `-dev`.

Comment: @Barmar - I've edited the pattern to include `$` (end of string) so the negative lookahead matches only at end of string.  Now I think should be what OP is asking however his question is a bit confusing..